# Logic to parse specific html tag in given string and build collection of different type of string

Tags: c#, string, logic

I want to write a logic for below scenario, need ideas on best implementation for it -

1. I have 3 types of text. Type1:- High,   Type2: Medium,    Type3: Low
2. I represent each of these text in different way in HTML as below  -
     for Type 1:- High -> Html would look like this

   > <font color=Red><b>Sample High Text</b></font>

   for Type 2:- Medium -> Html would look like this

   > <font color=Blue><u>Sample Medium Text></u></font>

   for Type 3:- Low -> No Html, its plain text

   > Sample Low Text
3. So I have  resultant string something like this -

   > <font color=Red><b>Sample High Text</b></font> Sample Low Text><font color=Blue><u>Sample Medium Text></u></font>
4. I want to build back a collection having a text and its type

The resultant string would contain only above mentioned html and no other html would be there.

Please suggest good approach for this logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should split input line to separate text blocks, and then determine type for each text block:

```
enum TextType
{ 
    High,
    Medium,
    Low
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var html = "<font color=Red><b>Sample High Text</b></font>Sample Low Text<font color=Blue><u>Sample Medium Text</u></font>";
        var rawStrings = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(html, "(?=<font)|(</font>)");
        var nonEmptyRawStrings = rawStrings.Select(s => System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(s, "</font>|</u>|</b>", ""))
            .Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            .ToList();

        const string highPrefix = "<font color=Red><b>";
        const string mediumPrefix = "<font color=Blue><u>";

        var typedString = nonEmptyRawStrings.Select(s => new
        {
            Type = s.StartsWith(highPrefix) ? TextType.High : (s.StartsWith(mediumPrefix) ? TextType.Medium : TextType.Low),
            String = s.Replace(highPrefix, "").Replace(mediumPrefix, "")
        }).ToList();

        typedString.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine("Type: {0}\tString: {1}", s.Type, s.String));
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks PashaPash this is much cleaner and perfect solution than I thought.